# OnSelectedIndexChanged causes a full page refresh/postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I leave the AutoPostBack property, it doesn't fire, if I have it in there, it refreshes the whole page. Code snippet is below:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddClientName" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsClients" DataTextField="Client_Name" DataValueField="Client_Name" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddClientName_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Client_Name") %>' MaxLength="255"></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour. If you want to do a partial refresh wrap it in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx):

```
<asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <contenttemplate>    
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddClientName" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsClients" DataTextField="Client_Name" DataValueField="Client_Name" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddClientName_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>    
    </contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Comment: I've tried the above and get the following error:  Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField' does not have a public property named 'UpdatePanel'.

Comment: Where is your DropDownList located? What's `InsertItemTemplate` a part of - GridView?